# Область на экране не реагирует на касания

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, xcode

Ситуация така. на `ViewController` добавляю `UIView` со скроллом и кнопкой, ничего необычного. Но половина экрана (Я выделил белую область на фотошопе см. скрин) она просто не кликается. За белой областью, полностью функционирует, но если пытаешься что-то сделать в рамках белой области программа никак не реагирует. Ни на скролл, ни на кнопку. Кстати кусок скрола, который находиться на пределом белой области тоже корректно работает.

P.S. На скрине в режиме отладки включено "Слои смешевая цвета" что б было видно что на белой области больше ничего нет. 
P.S.S Белый цвет что б было понятнее где программа не реагирует на клик
P.S.S.S Фрем задан как и положенно 1024/768 (проверял)

[image][image]

Comment: Белая область на глаз начерчена?

Comment: задайте каждому вью разный контрастный цвет и посмотрите реальные их размеры и что где лежит. К тому же выставьте clipsToBounds = YES,  это также может вам помочь увидеть где проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А все супервью имеют такой же размер? В айоси виды по умолчанию не обрезаются по размеру того, на чем они лежат, а область касания обрезается.

Вообще размер наводит на мысли что у кого-то из лежащих ближе к окну вьюх стоит портретная ориентация

Comment: @aknew Ты был прав, спасибо, пофиксил!